# (roblox) how do i make a script run only when someone joins a game for the first time

Tags: lua, roblox

so i am trying to make a tutorial for new players which pops up when they join for the first time. obviously i only want this to pop up if they have not played before. I know how to make the tutorial, just not how to make it so it only happens when the player is new, How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Btw this is taken off of the code is taken off of the devfourm, Here is the link https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-can-i-tell-if-a-player-is-joining-for-the-first-time/1244979/7

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("New_Player")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
   if DataStore:GetAsync(Player.UserId.."-HasSeen") then
       wait()
   else
       --CODE HERE
       DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId.."-HasSeen", true)
   end
end)
```